# Is it viable to start with Catalyst while learning Perl?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm not quite sure that this is on-topic (if it isn't, I'll delete it ASAP =)).

I've decided to start teaching myself Perl and how to use it for web development. 
I've done the same about a year ago with Python, and although I'm not an expert (I code in Java during work hours, and spend some personal time trying out other stuff), I've been able to create some websites using Django, and I've used ProjectEuler problems to get to know the basics of the language.

From my first approaches, Perl seems to have a steeper learning curve then Python.

I've been looking at some Web dev. frameworks for Perl and stumbled upon Catalyst, which seems very interesting.

**My question here is**: Is it even worth it to try it out while still struggling a bit with the language, or will I be wasting my time? Should I master Perl first, and then perhaps CGI before jumping into a framework that probably abstracts many concepts from the developer?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Voting to close as per [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): not constructive/soliciting debate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Catalyst is a great framework, and Perl is a great language.  I don't know about the steeper learning curve part - I don't know any of the other languages.

As to learning Perl whilst learning Catalyst, this is almost exactly what I did.  Work required that I produce something with a web interface. I ran into Catalyst and thought, '*Great, that sounds easy*'.  Well… it is and it isn't. There are learning curves with everything and Catalyst, like the rest of Perl, gives you plenty of rope — more than enough to hang yourself with.

The way to keep that from happening is to read the Catalyst book, and read some generic Perl books.  I'm from a background of UNIX/Linux, so I also read [Minimal Perl](http://www.manning.com/maher/) by Tim Maher, and find it extremely helpful — I go back to it constantly.

[CPAN](http://cpan.org) is really helpful with Catalyst — so many people have come up with ways to do "it", and Catalyst can work with pretty much all of it.

Also, make sure you head over to irc.perl.org and listen in on the conversations in the #catalyst and #dbix-class channels. Use #perl on freenode as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can fumble through Perl while you use Catalyst. Here's a great [book on Catalyst](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223650).

My opinion is that learning CGI would teach you the theory behind the framework. You may or may not want that. I think people learn a lot of the theory over time as they become a more advanced user of the framework.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reference to the book! I'll definitly look into it!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Catalyst while learning Perl.

Perl + Catalyst + Catalyst Tutorials + Modern Perl book = awesome (use in the same time)

Answer (score 3):

You might start with a "microframework" like [Dancer](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer) if you want to more-quickly reach a point where you're productive in your learning phase. Catalyst is very good but has its own learning curve, especially if you're also new to Perl.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should first start to explore the differences to other languages, which make perl such a good alternative to the classic programming languages. After this I would recommend to start with Catalyst for deepening your skills ;)